# Is there a potentially subversive bias with the badge and reputation system?

Tags: discussion

I'll admit it , I am swayed by fancy rep and badges. Sometimes I run across questions from users who  are high-ranking and obviously veterans, but they're posting one-liners. And I hate to say it, but I'm shying away from downvoting them. Why?

I guess because there's an assumption that someone with such big rep must know what they're doing.

My question is this - what can we do to partially counter this bias. I.E if I see `user128749128` with 1 rep, I should *not* treat them differently than `KingOFStack` with 77K rep and Gold, Silver, and Bronze badges

Because intuitively, I know we *do* treat those two users differently. For the latter, we are much more forgiving it seems. I'm not sure how to prove this though, but I'm certain of it. But is that fair?

I am somewhat reminded by the "acceptance percentage" controversy. i.e in the past, we had the acceptance percentage and you could easily point at it and say "hey you have a lousy acceptance % go fix that!!", and although the badges aren't the same... it's something of a potential "noise-factor"

Comment: This has been discussed before, but this definitely is an issue. I've noticed that since reaching 2-3k, people seem to be more likely to upvote my answers, even though some of my best answers are from before. Note that I tend to downvote bad answers frequently.

Comment: `what can we do to partially counter this bias` Don't be hesitant to downvote bad answers, and give equal scrutiny to all posts? Not sure what the system could do to counter this, short of hiding the reputation count - which is never going to fly, and would arguably be very silly.

Comment: @Pëkka  - point taken. I'm sort of just venting a little bit I guess. I will aim to be more fair in downvoting.

Comment: +1 just for the irony of it. ;)

Comment: @Doorknob - *Staaaaahhhhhp!* ! :D  :P

Comment: Some to get started on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1666987, http://stackoverflow.com/a/377263, http://stackoverflow.com/a/187075 :)

Comment: @UphillLuge Awesome! These are perfect :D